# Knockout select change event not firing

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

I have multiple dropdowns which bind to my view model of items - this collection is refreshed when a user performs an action elsewhere. The problem I am having is that the change event is not firing -

```
                <div id="case-pin-@modelItem.CaseID" class="row hidden popovercontainer pinBinding">
                    <select id="pingroup_@modelItem.CaseID"
                            data-bind="options: userPins, optionsCaption:'-- please select --', optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Id', event: { change: function(data, event) { pinChanged(data, event,'@modelItem.CaseID') } }"></select>
                </div>
```

I have tried to the subscribe (but this would not work with the optionsCaption specified) as well as the event.

```
function UserPinViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.userPins = ko.observableArray([]);
    //self.selectedPin = ko.observable();

    //self.selectedPin.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    //    console.log(newValue);
    //});

    self.pinChanged = function (data, event, caseId) {
        alert(caseId);
    }
}

var objPin;

$(function () {
    objPin = new UserPinViewModel();

    $(".pinBinding").each(function () {
        ko.cleanNode(this);
        ko.applyBindings(objPin, this);
    });
})
```

The reason I need to use an event instead of subscribing is because I need the identifier to determine which entity the dropdown has been changed one as well as the new value selected.

**EDIT**

So modified the code based upon the comment provided, however, the alert in the subscription is still not firing ...

```
function UserPinViewModel(caseId) {
    var self = this;
    self.userPins = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedPin = ko.observable();
    self.caseId = caseId;

    self.selectedPin.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        alert(newValue);
    });
}

var pinObjs = [];

$(function () {
    pinObjs = [];

    $(".pinBinding").each(function () {
        var caseId = this.getAttribute("data-caseid");
        var view = new UserPinViewModel(caseId);
        pinObjs.push(view);

        ko.cleanNode(this);
        ko.applyBindings(view, this);
    });
})
```

The alert in the subscription is not fired...

```
                <div id="case-pin-@modelItem.CaseID" data-caseid="@modelItem.CaseID" class="row hidden popovercontainer pinBinding">
                    <select data-bind="options: userPins,
                            optionsCaption:'-- please select --',
                            optionsText: 'Name',
                            optionsValue: 'Id',
                            value: selectedPin"></select>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using the `event` binding is the way to go. To me it looks like it would be logical to create a view model for each select box. You can then store the `CaseID` property in a viewmodel, rather than trying to access it through the bindings. You can still "inject" it via the DOM, if that suits the way you're working.

Staying close to your current approach, you could do something like this:

```
<div id="case-pin-@modelItem.CaseID" data-caseid="@modelItem.CaseID">...</div>
```

And

```
$(".pinBinding").each(function () {
    var caseId = this.getAttribute("data-caseid");
    var vm = new UserPinViewModel(caseId);

    ko.cleanNode(this);
    ko.applyBindings(vm, this);
});
```

With a modified viewmodel:

```
function UserPinViewModel(caseId) {
  var self = this;

  self.userPins = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedPin = ko.observable();

  self.selectedPin.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue, caseId);
  });
}
```

The `options` bind can work with `value`, because the `caseId` was passed to the viewmodel earlier on.

```
<select data-bind="options: userPins, 
                   optionsCaption:'-- please select --', 
                   optionsText: 'Name', 
                   optionsValue: 'Id',
                   value: selectedPin"></select>
```

Note that, if the `selectedPin` and `userPins` property *need* to be shared between the select boxes, you'll have to create observables that are shared by the viewmodels but initialized someplace else...

**Edit:** Your updated code seems to work...

```js
function UserPinViewModel(caseId) {
  var self = this;
  self.userPins = ko.observableArray([{
    Name: "Pin 1",
    Id: "1"
  }, {
    Name: "Pin 2",
    Id: "2"
  }]);
  self.selectedPin = ko.observable();
  self.caseId = caseId;

  self.selectedPin.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    alert("Pin:" + newValue + ", case: " + self.caseId);
  });
}

var pinObjs = [];

$(function() {
  pinObjs = [];

  $(".pinBinding").each(function() {
    var caseId = this.getAttribute("data-caseid");
    var view = new UserPinViewModel(caseId);
    pinObjs.push(view);

    ko.cleanNode(this);
    ko.applyBindings(view, this);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="case-pin-@modelItem.CaseID" data-caseid="testCaseId1" class="row hidden popovercontainer pinBinding">
  <select data-bind="options: userPins,
                     optionsCaption:'-- please select --',
                     optionsText: 'Name',
                     optionsValue: 'Id',
                     value: selectedPin"></select>
</div>

<div id="case-pin-@modelItem.CaseID" data-caseid="testCaseId2" class="row hidden popovercontainer pinBinding">
  <select data-bind="options: userPins,
                     optionsCaption:'-- please select --',
                     optionsText: 'Name',
                     optionsValue: 'Id',
                     value: selectedPin"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding data bind my required identifiers using the data-... tag - learn something new everyday. It is still not working as I expect however, I will update the original question, with the latest code

Comment: Interestingly, if I remove the optionsCaption from the data-bind, its fires on load but not when it is changed thereafter... but I need the default option in

Comment: With the `optionsCaption`, the initial value of `selectedPin` will be set to `undefined`, which won't trigger the subscription since it was already initialized as `undefined`. When you remove it, knockout sets the first option, which _does_ trigger the subscription.

Comment: I've pasted your updated code into my answer and it seems to work fine...

Comment: It must be something else then, as I am still getting the alert on load but not when actually changing it - but in isolation, it works perfectly as you mention

Comment: I'm still struggling to get it working to be honest - I wonder if it is to do with the async server call to get the pins and set the userPins observable array which is causing the problem?

Comment: You'd want to make sure you reuse the parts of your viewmodels that hold the state. The cleaning and reapplying of bindings worries me a bit to be honest. But you'll have to show how you're loading your data... Might be a good idea to formulate a new question if it's a "new" problem you're facing.

Comment: Ok thanks for the input - the problem is still the same however, as the subscription event is not being fired when changing the value in the dropdown.